# Animation of a UIImage moving from one UIImageView to another

Tags: iphone, uiviewanimation, caanimation

I've managed to get along using [UIView animateWithDuration... to get animations done that I need in my UI.  Now I want to move an image along a curved path, and that whole CAAnimation cluster looks pretty daunting to me.

I'd be much obliged if someone could help me fill in the method I wish I could code, which would look like this:

```
- (void)makeAnImageFlyFrom:(UIImageView *)imageViewA to:(UIImageView *)imageViewB alongPath:(CGMutablePathRef)path duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

    UIImage *imageToFly = imageViewA.image;
    // magic, that i'm too lazy to learn right now goes here
    // image flys along the path and gets scaled to match imageViewB.

    // then view/layer hierarchy is just as it was, but imageViewB has a new image
    // maybe this happens on animationDidStop...
    imageViewB.image = imageToFly;

}
```

Feel free to replace params (like path ref) if you think there's a smarter interface for this kind of method.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's pretty much the information you need to construct a CAKeyframeAnimation, q.v. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAKeyframeAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: http://bill.dudney.net/roller/objc/entry/keyframe_animation

Comment: I figured the half-page of broken stuff I've got right now would be harder to answer (and send answers off in the wrong direction due to my mistakes) then asking for a clean slate.  This seems to me a specific operation that someone with more experience would have readily handy in their bag of tricks.  CAAnimation, CALayer, CAAnimationGroup, CATimingFunction, CGPath etc. is a pretty big learning curve to move an image.  Is there an obvious answer somewhere that any rube should have figured out with a moment's attention?  Put it in an answer that insults me and I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, a whole Sunday later, here's a method that I think works.  I'm still unclear about a few things, noted in comments, but if you need this type of thing, feel free to cut and paste.  I promise not call you lazy:

```
- (void)makeAnImageFlyFrom:(UIImageView *)imageViewA to:(UIImageView *)imageViewB duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

    // it's simpler but less general to not pass in the path.  i chose simpler because
    // there's a lot of geometry work using the imageView frames here anyway.

    UIImageView *animationView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imageViewA.image];
    animationView.tag = kANIMATION_IMAGE_TAG;
    animationView.frame = imageViewA.frame;
    [self addSubview:animationView];

    // scale
    CABasicAnimation *resizeAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"bounds.size"];
    [resizeAnimation setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCGSize:imageViewA.bounds.size]];
    [resizeAnimation setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGSize:imageViewB.bounds.size]];

    // build the path
    CGRect aRect = [imageViewA convertRect:imageViewA.bounds toView:self];
    CGRect bRect = [imageViewB convertRect:imageViewB.bounds toView:self];

    // unclear why i'm doing this, but the rects converted to this view's
    // coordinate system seemed have origin's offset negatively by half their size
    CGFloat startX = aRect.origin.x + aRect.size.width / 2.0;
    CGFloat startY = aRect.origin.y + aRect.size.height / 2.0;
    CGFloat endX = bRect.origin.x + bRect.size.width / 2.0;
    CGFloat endY = bRect.origin.y + bRect.size.height / 2.0;

    CGFloat deltaX = endX - startX;
    CGFloat deltaY = endY - startY;

    // these control points suited the path i needed.  your results may vary
    CGFloat cp0X = startX + 0.3*deltaX;
    CGFloat cp0Y = startY - 1.3*deltaY;
    CGFloat cp1X = endX + 0.1*deltaX;
    CGFloat cp1Y = endY - 0.5*deltaY;

    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, startX, startY);
    CGPathAddCurveToPoint(path, NULL, cp0X, cp0Y, cp1X, cp1Y, endX, endY);

    // keyframe animation
    CAKeyframeAnimation *keyframeAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    keyframeAnimation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;
    keyframeAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    keyframeAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    keyframeAnimation.path = path;

    // assuming i need to manually release, despite ARC, but not sure
    CGPathRelease(path);

    // a little unclear about the fillMode, but it works
    // also unclear about removeOnCompletion, because I remove the animationView
    // but that seems to be insufficient
    CAAnimationGroup *group = [CAAnimationGroup animation]; 
    group.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    group.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    [group setAnimations:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:keyframeAnimation, resizeAnimation, nil]];
    group.duration = duration;
    group.delegate = self;

    // unclear about what i'm naming with the keys here, and why
    [group setValue:animationView forKey:@"animationView"];

    [animationView.layer addAnimation:group forKey:@"animationGroup"];
}

// clean up after like this

- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag
{
    UIImageView *imageViewForAnimation = (UIImageView *)[self viewWithTag:kANIMATION_IMAGE_TAG];
    // get the imageView passed to the animation as the destination
    UIImageView *imageViewB = (UIImageView *)[self viewWithTag:kDEST_TAG];

    imageViewB.image = imageViewForAnimation.image;
    [imageViewForAnimation removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: oh god! Really helpful dude..who told you are lazy!..just 1 confusion..where do you add kDEST_TAG?

Comment: thanks.  it's just a #define of an int tag.  assign it to the image view where you want the image to fly:  #define kDEST_TAG 128  then imageViewDestination.tag = kDEST_TAG.

Comment: i've refined this code somewhat since then.  lemme know if you need help or a variant and i'll supply.

Comment: yeah sure..it will be very helpful if you could share some code with me...right now am using your code in my project...adjusted those values of cgpath to customize the path....hw cn i cntct you?

Comment: Here's my latest stuff http://pastebin.com/FZXvRDS2.  The new interface lets you specify a rectangle destination (instead of an imageView) and a block that gets called on completion.  In the block you can then assign the image to another UIImageView, or do whatever else you want.  It also does a better job computing the path for the animation.

Comment: @MilKyWaY - i had to tweak that code from my project to make it more general for you.  that caused me to make an error.  before line 10 in that paste bin, add the line self.animationParent = parent;

Comment: hey, that looks really great, btw, i use your code and it works pretty well, but the issue am facing right now is... here we are applying  a group of animations (scaling and transform) right..i need to apply the animation to more than 1 images at the same time, ie, need to animate more images in an elliptical path, somewhat like a coverflow ...any idea? if its not clear, i can share some screen shots with you

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24162/discussion-between-danh-and-milkyway)

Comment: Will you please check this?                               [imageView2 flyToRect:imageView1.frame insideParentView:self.view completion:^(UIImage *image) {
                imageView1.image=image;
    }];                                                              this fails to set the new image to the image view.How can I set the swiped image to nexyt image view on completion?

Comment: @MilKyWaY - i'm sorry about this.  i had to touch that stuff to take out stuff private to a customer.  maybe i busted it.  i'll have some time to investigate this weekend, and i'll get some working stuff to you.

Comment: @MilKyWaY - I updated and tested this.  It should work for you.  Instructions in the paste bin.  Good luck!  http://pastebin.com/1aYVxQzX

Comment: hey did you try this in "device"? In simulator the transmission looks fine, but when we try in device, it causes a flickering like effect while the image view reaches the destination, any idea why this happens?

Comment: Do you have any idea why this shows a flickering effect while running in iPad, at the time we change the image on animation complete action?

Comment: @danh i reworked your (first) pastebin to be a little leaner with a wrapper to allow for flying existing views. http://pastebin.com/JHnBq4Dj call it like this [CAAnimationBlockDelegate flyImageFrom:section toRect:source.frame completion:^(CAAnimationBlockDelegate *worker) {[/* clean up code here */worker release];}] retain];